# @DBLookup and image display on web

Tags: lotus-domino

I am having issues with displaying an image in a Rich Text field on Notes document on the web.  On web form, I have a form with a computed Rich Text field with this logic for the value:

```
 @DbLookup("":"NoCache";"":@DbName;"notices";"americas-en-LoginMsg";"Error_Body";[FailSilent])
```

The source document is different than the destination document.
When The Web form opens up, only the formatted text displays and the image is just a placeholder with no image displaying.  Any ideas on how to get it displayed.  Using `Domino server vers. 9.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the image(s) in Resources>Images area of the database and used pass thru HTML on source document to reference it (them):  img src="https://something.com/webpages/database.nsf/Buyback.gif?OpenImageResource" (with proper formatting of course).